# Parsing arguments in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a question about parsing arguments in Python. Example code below.

```
Class Parser:
     def __init__(self):
         self.args = argparse.ArgumentParser()
         self.args.add_argument("--email")
         self.args.add_argument("--file")
         self.args.add_argument("--save")
         self.args.add_argument("--time")
     
         self.args_parsed = self.args.parse_args()

    def get_email(self):
        return self.args_parsed.email

    def get_file(self):
        return self.args_parsed.file

    def get_save(self):
        return self.args_parsed.save

    def get_time(self):
        return self.args_parsed.time

Class functions(Parser):
      def __init__(self):
          super().__init__()

      def Function1(self):
          pass

      def Function2(self):
          pass

      def Function3(self):
          pass

      def Function4(self):
          pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
  try:
     arguments = sys.argv[1:]
    
     if "--file" in arguments:
        Function1()
     elif "--save" in arguments:
          Function2()
     elif "--email" in arguments:
          Function3()
     elif "--time" in arguments:
          Function4()
  except IndexError:
       print("Invalid argument")
```

Basically what my question is I want to add a lot more options then I already have, and I would have to keep on continuing the if elif chain. Is there a way to reduce this to only parse the arguments the user chooses? thanks

I know that you can do something like this:

```
my_dict = {
            "file": Function1,
            "save": Function2,
            "email": Function3,
            "time": Function4
        }
if __name__ == '__main__':
   try:
      arguments = sys.argv[1]
      
      if arguments:
         my_dicts[arguments]()
```

But how can I do that with multiple values?

Comment: I think you'll find that, once you start actually writing all those functions, they need specific arguments as well, or may require values from other options. It makes more sense to deal with each option in context of what it means, instead of just blatantly calling a function for each option and be done with it. For example: `download.py https://mydata.com --port 8080 --no-redirect --output-folder C:\Temp` - in this example, none of the options map directly to just a basic function - they are only meaningful together and their values can be read directly from the parsed options.

Comment: You're not even using the `Parser` class.

Comment: @Grismar Is there an example for that? I only know how to pass functions to one value in a dictionary

Comment: I'm afraid I'll have to point you to the documentation and examples for `argparse` - if you share more about what you're actually trying to do and provide an example of the code you're using, people could give you more direct advice. It seems you're only looking to pass in some values (e-mail, output file, etc.) and you don't really need functions for those - perhaps you can give a simple example that shows why you think a function is needed and what you do with the parameter afterwards, so people can suggest a way forward.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that could help you:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import argparse

def email_handler(email_argument):
    print(f'The email {email_argument} has been chosen')

def file_handler(file_argument):
    print('I have to do something different with this file:', 
          file_argument)

def save_handler(save_argument):
    print('Maybe you want to save', save_argument)

def time_handler(time_argument):
    print(f'We have to take time {time_argument} into account')

options_handlers = {
    'email' : email_handler,
    'file' : file_handler,
    'save' : save_handler,
    'time' : time_handler
}

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
for current_option in options_handlers:
    parser.add_argument(f'--{current_option}')

arguments_extracted = parser.parse_args()

arguments_accessible = vars(arguments_extracted)

for (current_argument, current_value) in arguments_accessible.items():
    if current_value is not None:
        current_handler = options_handlers[current_argument]
        current_handler(current_value)
```